# Input string was not in correct format and remove drop down items from drop down

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, drop-down-menu

I have a requirement where i have to remove the drop down items depending upon the start date and end date.
I have googled enough and tried many simple ways such as i could remove the selected item in drop down.
The issue here is, It throws error that input string was not in correct format and how to trace and remove the item from the drop down.
Please note that the drop down value are begin binded from calender list and it has been displayed in custom list as drop down (hope it is clear).

Below are my code:

```
protected void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SPSite oSPSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
        SPWeb oSPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists["Registered"];
        SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = oSPList.Items;
        SPListItem oSPListItem = oSPListItemCollection.Add();
        DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();
        oSPListItem["Employee Name"] = oSPWeb.CurrentUser.Email.ToString();
        string[] UsersSeperated = peopleEditorManager.CommaSeparatedAccounts.Split(',');
        SPFieldUserValueCollection UserCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
        SPFieldUserValue UserName = new SPFieldUserValue();
        foreach (string UserSeperated in UsersSeperated)
        {
            oSPWeb.EnsureUser(UserSeperated);
            SPUser User = oSPWeb.SiteUsers[UserSeperated];
            UserName = new SPFieldUserValue(oSPWeb, User.ID, User.LoginName);
            UserCollection.Add(UserName);
        }
        oSPListItem["peopleEditorManager"] = UserCollection;
        oSPListItem["Practice Name"] = TxtPracticeName.Text;
        oSPListItem["Course Name"] = ddlDrop.SelectedItem;
        oSPListItem["Prerequisite"] = TxtPrerequisite1.Text;
        oSPListItem["Beg Date"] = TxtStartDate.Text;
        oSPListItem["Finish Date"] = TxtEndDate.Text;
        string registeredCourse = oSPListItem["Course Name"].ToString();
        SPList oSPListCourse = oSPWeb.Lists["Scheduled Courses"];
        SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollectionCourse = oSPListCourse.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem oSPListItemCourse in oSPListItemCollectionCourse)
        {
            string begginingDate = oSPListItemCourse["Start Date"].ToString();
            string finishDate = oSPListItemCourse["End Date"].ToString();
            //input string not in correct format
            if (( Convert.ToInt32(begginingDate) >= Convert.ToInt32(TxtStartDate.Text) ) 
                || (Convert.ToInt32(finishDate) <= Convert.ToInt32(TxtEndDate.Text))) 
            {
                //how to remove the item from drop down if their date is greater than StartDate and less than EndDate
                ddlDrop.Items.Remove(ddlDrop.SelectedItem);
            }
        }  
        oSPListItem.Update();
        LblMessage.Text = "Registeres";
        String fromID = oSPWeb.CurrentUser.Email.ToString();
        String mailTo = UserName.User.Email.ToString();
        string titleName = ddlDrop.SelectedItem.ToString();
        SendEmail_WU(fromID, mailTo, titleName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> how to remove the item from drop down if their date is greater than StartDate and less than EndDate

it sounds like you should be using [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of Convert.ToInt32.

Also, your comment says "and" but the `||` in your code says "or". And the left and right sides of your condition need to be flipped.

The following code should implement what your comment expresses:

```
//input string not in correct format
if ((Convert.ToDateTime(TxtStartDate.Text) > Convert.ToDateTime(begginingDate)) 
    && (Convert.ToDateTime(TxtEndDate.Text) < Convert.ToDateTime(finishDate))) 
{
    // how to remove the item from drop down if their date is 
    // greater than StartDate and less than EndDate
    ddlDrop.Items.Remove(ddlDrop.SelectedItem);
}
```

If this does not do what you want, then you need to revisit your requirement.