# Input string was not in correct format.How to correct it?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, drop-down-menu

I have a requirement where i have to remove the drop down items depending upon the start date and end date.
The issue here is, It throws error that input string was not in correct format.

```
foreach (SPListItem oSPListItemCourse in oSPListItemCollectionCourse)
{
string begginingDate = oSPListItemCourse["Start Date"].ToString();
string finishDate = oSPListItemCourse["End Date"].ToString();
if (( Convert.ToInt32(begginingDate)>=Convert.ToInt32(TxtStartDate.Text) ) || (Convert.ToInt32(finishDate)<= Convert.ToInt32(TxtEndDate.Text)))//input string not in correct format
{
ddlDrop.Items.Remove(ddlDrop.SelectedItem);//how to remove the item from drop down if their date is greater than StartDate and less than EndDate
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input string was not in correct format and remove drop down items from drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477248/input-string-was-not-in-correct-format-and-remove-drop-down-items-from-drop-down)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the startdate and end date value to DateTime Format rather than to a string.

Comment: My requirement is to convert to string:(

Comment: Then Why are you checking the condition as integer value ? if that is the requirement then begining itself convert into int.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert date string to integer value. What did you expect as result?
If you want to compare two dates just convert all values to DateTime and compare them.